# Tailwind CSS Compilation Error with Custom Class in Next.js Project

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, compiler-errors, tailwind-css

I'm working on a Next.js project with Tailwind CSS and I've encountered a compilation error that I can't seem to resolve. The error is related to a custom utility class I've defined in my theme.css file. Here's the error message:

Failed to compile

```
./styles/theme.css:7:9
Syntax error: D:\Developer\Projects\Nextjs13\nextapp\styles\theme.css The `bg-light-850` class does not exist. If `bg-light-850` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.

  5 | @layer utilities {
  6 |     .background-light850_dark100 {
> 7 |         @apply bg-light-850 dark:bg-dark-100;
    |         ^
  8 |     }
  9 |     .background-light900_dark200 {
```

In my theme.css file, I have:

```
@layer utilities {
    .background-light850_dark100 {
        @apply bg-light-850 dark:bg-dark-100;
    }
    // ... other classes ...
}
```

And my tailwind.config.ts includes:

```
// ... other config settings ...

extend: {
  colors: {
    // ... other colors ...
    light: {
      900: '#FFFFFF',
      800: '#F4F6F8',
      850: '#FDFDFD',
      // ... other light colors ...
    },
    // ... other color settings ...
  },
  // ... other extended theme settings ...
}

// ... rest of the configuration ...
```

As you can see, light-850 is defined in my Tailwind configuration, but the compiler does not seem to recognize it. I have tried clearing the Next.js cache and rebuilding the project, but the issue persists.

Could anyone help me understand why this error is occurring and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Rebuild, remove cache, asked copilot.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I discovered the issue was linked to the content array in my tailwind.config.ts. This array tells Tailwind where to look for class names. In my project, the array included a variety of file types (.js, .ts, .jsx, .tsx, .mdx), but it turned out that my theme.css file, which contained the custom class, wasn't being correctly processed.

To resolve this, I made sure that the theme.css file was located in one of the directories listed in the content array. I also ensured the syntax in theme.css was correct, particularly the use of the @apply directive and CSS comment syntax.

Additionally, I cleared the project cache and rebuilt it, which is crucial for changes in the Tailwind configuration to take effect. This step resolved the error, and the custom class was recognized without issues.

It's essential to ensure consistency in the file types included in your Tailwind content array and to verify the location and syntax of your custom CSS files.